# Visual Studio - Menu items and toolbar buttons missing after deleting a resource

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2008

Something very strange happened here in Visual Studio 2008 (C#).

After deleting an icon resource from my project all my menu items and toolbar buttons disappeared. I checked my form Designer.cs file and the code to the items are still there. Also, I tried to search for the deleted resource file name (warning.ico) in the entire solution, and nothing was found.

What happened and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just discovered.

Somehow, Visual Studio messed the Designer.cs file of my form.
After close inspection, the AddRange Method of my menu and toolbar was missing.

Just fixed manually by adding:

`this.mainToolbar.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] { this.lsbPort });`

Answer (score 4):

This bug still persists in VS2010. It happened to me after changing the location of an image resource outside of VS. VS reported an error and I relinked to the new location. Everything appeared fine until the next start of Visual Studio. All controls (including separators) of any toolbar in my application were gone.

All I can say is: the fix still works as described.

**Edit:** And the bug persists in VS2015. And (as I have just found out) in VS2019